# Find frequency of a custom word in R TermDocumentMatrix using TM package

Tags: r, tm, corpus, word-frequency, term-document-matrix

I turned about 50,000 rows of varchar data into a corpus, and then proceeded to clean said corpus using the TM package, getting ride of stopwords, punctuation, and numbers.

I then turned it into a TermDocumentMatrix and used the functions findFreqTerms and findMostFreqTerms to run text analysis. findMostFreqTerms return the common words, and the number of times it shows up in the data.

However, I want to use a function that says search for "word" and return how many times "word" appears in the TermDocumentMatrix.

Is there a function in TM that achieves this? Do I have to change my data to a data.frame and use a different package & function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not given a reproducible example, I will give one using the `crude` dataset available in the `tm` package.

You can do it in (at least) 2 different ways. But anything that turns a sparse matrix into a dense matrix can use a lot of memory. So I will give you 2 options. The first one is more memory friendly as it makes use of the sparse tdm matrix. The second one, first transforms the tdm into a dense matrix before creating a frequency vector.

```
library(tm)
data("crude")
crude <- as.VCorpus(crude)
crude <- tm_map(crude, stripWhitespace)
crude <- tm_map(crude, removePunctuation)
crude <- tm_map(crude, content_transformer(tolower))
crude <- tm_map(crude, removeWords, stopwords("english"))


tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude)

# Making use of the fact that a tdm or dtm is a simple_triplet_matrix from slam
my_func <- function(data, word){
  slam::row_sums(data[data$dimnames$Terms == word, ])
}

my_func(tdm, "crude")
crude 
   21 
my_func(tdm, "oil")
oil 
 85

# turn tdm into dense matrix and create frequency vector. 
freq <- rowSums(as.matrix(tdm))
freq["crude"]
crude 
   21 
freq["oil"]
oil 
 85
```

*edit:*
As requested in comment:

```
# all words starting with cru. Adjust regex to find what you need.
freq[grep("^cru", names(freq))]
crucial   crude 
      2      21 

# separate words
freq[c("crude", "oil")]
crude   oil 
   21    85
```

Comment: apologies for not providing sample data, but converting tdm into a dense metrix and creating frequency vector worked. Thank you. Is it possible to search for multiple iterations of words at once with wildcards, e.g. freq ["crude%"]? Is it possible to get count of two separate words, e.g. freq["crude" , "oil"]?

Comment: @George, I edited my answers to include these 2 examples

Comment: fantastic! Last question, in order to search for bigrams and trigrams (2 or 3 consecutive words), do I have to use RWeka package? or in current form of the data, can I use the freq function to search freq["not fit"]

Comment: No you do not need to use RWeka if you do not want to (saves on rjava dependencies). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50114633/dict-function-for-ngrams/50114876#50114876) you can find an answer of me that just uses NLP to create bigrams. Change the 2 into a 3 and you get trigrams. The advantage of RWeka is that you can create a tokenizer that does bigram and trigram in one go. freq["not fit"] does currently not exist since the default is to separate each word.

Comment: Hey @phiver. how can you search for multiple words with wildcards using grep function? this syntax isn't working. Basically, you're second example, but if crude and oil had wildcards                                     freq[grep("does", names(text)), grep("align", names(text))]

Comment: regex procedures :-). use e.g. grep("^cru|^oil", .....). Check some regex tutorials /websites on how to use the magic power of regex :-)

Comment: For me solution 2 (the dense matrix's) didn't work with my dataset due to memory limitations.